# R tm package - controlling edge weights and colors

Tags: r, graph, plot, tm

I am trying to plot a graph with weighted and colored edges using tm package in R. The issue is that the correlations are pretty strong so the edges width covers most of my plot. I can control the fact they are weighted though no success in coloring them in light grey so it won't cover the rest of the graph.
My code is:

```
plot(dtm,terms = findFreqTerms(dtm, lowfreq=400),corThreshold = 0.3,weighting = TRUE,attrs = list(graph = list(rankdir ="BT"),node = list(shape = "rectangle",fixedsize=FALSE,fontsize=120)))
```

which is working fine except the very wide and dark edges.

An alternative solution I thought about is transforming the object to a graph object but no success with this either.

Any assistance will be highly appreciated. Many many thanks.